# PHP: proper way to detect browser language and redirect

Tags: php, redirect

I'm trying to redirect hits on https://www.mobilemultimedia.be to the one of the languages I'm supporting like https://www.mobilemultimedia.be/en/

If I detect a browser language in English, I use the following code:

```
$browser_language = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
http_response_code(301);
if (preg_match("/(fr|en|nl|it|es|de)/",$browser_language))
    {
        header("Location: ".$domain."/".$browser_language."/");
    }
else
    {
        header("Location: ".$domain."/en/");
    }
```

When I try it with my browser, it seems to work fine but if I use Google's indexation tool, it tells me that the page has a soft 404 and because of that it can't be indexed. I have set a http code 301 to avoid this but it doesn't seem to work.

If I check redirections with http://www.redirect-checker.org/index.php I see a 301 leading to the right page but if I test it with Google or Webpagetest.org or Pingdom tools, the redirection doesn't seem to work.

any idea?

Comment: can you post the code that you are using for language check please?

Comment: How do you detect the language? When I need to do, I parse the header. Example: `Accept-Language: en,de;q=0.5` tells en (English) is prefered, then de (German).

Comment: You detect whether `$browser_language` *contains* "fr", "en" etc, but it *could* be much more complex than that. You still just essentially redirect to `$domain/$HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE`, so that could be `$domain/en,de;q=0.5`…!

Comment: @deceze they are only working with first two characters, note the use of substr in the first line of shown code. That is of course still a pretty naive way of doing this, and does not even start to take stuff like the `q` quality factor into account.

Comment: @misorude You're right, I overlooked that.